# splitting pandas dataframe into training and test sets when indexed by time

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a dataframe indexed by time how can split it into training and test sets 2/3rds training and 1/3rd test?

Do I have to create a new column of continuously increasing integers and then use set_index() to the new integer column?

Or can I do it whilst keeping the time index? if so I have no idea how to do this.

Do I have to pick a date manually to act as the split point or is there some other way?

Comment: Why not just do `train_df = df.iloc[0: floor(2 * len(df) /3)]` and `test_df = df.iloc[floor(2 * len(df) /3):]`

Comment: Also consider [train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) which is an integer based indexing method, the fact the index is a time dtype is irrelevant when using `iloc`:

```
In [6]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['1','2','3','4','5']})
df.iloc[0: floor(2 * len(df)/3)]

C:\WinPython-64bit-3.3.5.0\python-3.3.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py:687: FutureWarning: slice indexers when using iloc should be integers and not floating point
  "and not floating point",FutureWarning)
Out[6]:
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
In [7]:

df.iloc[floor(2 * len(df) /3):]
Out[7]:
   a
3  4
4  5
```

You can ignore the warning here, the use of floor is because 3.3333 is not a valid index value

You can also use scikit-learns [cross-validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation) method which will return train-test split indices for you.

Comment: The other thing to consider is using scikit learn's [`cross-validation`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation) to evaluate your model